# Различие в инициализации коллекции List обычным способом и через индексацию

Tags: c#, list

Просто приведу два кусочка кода, которые должны быть идентичны по реализации.

```
Users.users = new List<User>
                              {
                                 [0] = Users.Admin
                              }; // Исключение
Users.users = new List<User>
                              {
                                 Users.Admin
                              }; // Все ок
```

Если что, это файл Data\Users.cs

Текст исключения:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Индекс за пределами диапазона.
> Индекс должен быть положительным числом, а его размер не должен
> превышать размер коллекции. Имя параметра: index

Различия - только в том кусочке кода, что я привел в начале вопроса.

Вот ссылка на проект на Git: [Проект на git](https://github.com/PI16a-GroupDynamics/Prime-Numbers.git)

Папка с exe, где вроде все ок: https://yadi.sk/d/N6tfBD0Y3SyNFW

Папка с exe, где исключение: https://yadi.sk/d/N6tfBD0Y3SyNFW

Как проявить это проблемное место:

1. Запустите exe (откроется окно типа "О программе")
2. Удалите папку Records, которая создалась рядом с экзешником
3. Закройте окно, обратите внимание на исключение.
4. Попробуйте проделать то же самое с "Хорошим" экзешником.

Так вот, откуда взялись различия, если код, по идее, не отличается?

Comment: А в чем проблема и сам вопрос-то?

Comment: Вопрос описал. Это можно обойти, но все же, "Почему?"

Comment: я так понимаю, если список пустой, то попытка обратиться к первому элементу будет неудачной

Comment: Это инициализация. Object initializer. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers    Сделайте поиск по "Можно указать индексированные элементы", найдет.

Comment: "Можно указать индексированные элементы, если коллекция поддерживает индексирование." Пример с Dictionary, сейчас проверю, может, вы и правы насчет пустой коллекции

Comment: Да, вы правы. Эта фишка - для словарей, а не для List. Жаль.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что ж, я нашел ответ. 
Инициализация индексированных элементов, как здесь

```
var numbers = new Dictionary<int, string> {   
[7] = "seven",   
[9] = "nine",   
[13] = "thirteen"   
};
```

- это для словарей. После создания словаря вызывается метод `Add(key, value)`, который и добавляет в словарь новый элемент.
В случае же с `List` : после создания нового List вызывается метод `Set(index, value)`, который не может присвоить значение из-за того, что index == размеру коллекции.

Если кто-то поймет IL код, то IL кода для этого участка кода

```
var list = new List<string>
                       {
                          [0] = "Hello"
                       };

        var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
                       {
                          [string.Empty] = "That's cool"
                       };
```

Будет таким:

```
// [183 13 - 186 30] 
IL_0000: newobj       instance void class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<string>::.ctor()
IL_0005: dup          
IL_0006: ldc.i4.0     
IL_0007: ldstr        "Hello"
IL_000c: callvirt     instance void class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<string>::set_Item(int32, !0/*string*/)
IL_0011: pop          

// [188 13 - 191 30]
IL_0012: newobj       instance void class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<string, string>::.ctor()
IL_0017: ldsfld       string [mscorlib]System.String::Empty
IL_001c: stloc.0      // V_0
IL_001d: dup          
IL_001e: ldloc.0      // V_0
IL_001f: ldstr        "That's cool"
IL_0024: callvirt     instance void class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<string, string>::set_Item(!0/*string*/, !1/*string*/)
IL_0029: pop
```